# Transmission can't download due to ufw

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw, bittorrent, transmission

I can't download anything in transmission because ufw firewall didn't allow

My ufw status is given below:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
51413/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   
51413                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
51413/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
51413 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

**N.B. : 51413 port is closed in transmission**

Here's a screenshot of Transmission's networking settings:

[image: Transmission Preferences dialog, Network tab, showing port 61453 in use, CLOSED, with random port selection and UPnP both enabled]

Comment: If you change the port used for incoming connections to 51413 and test the port, does it work as expected?

Comment: 51413 port   is closed in transmission

Comment: check if you have that port forwarded to your pc's ip in your router.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by performing following operations
1. Port Forwarding to router so that I download torrent file
2. Running following commands for uploading torrent

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -p udp --dport 51413 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 51413 -j ACCEPT
```

3. Allowed the same port in ufw

   sudo ufw allow 51413/udp

Reference: https://superuser.com/a/1006835/575722